# Exception logging missing caused by

Tags: java, logging, junit, logback

I have the following code sample that catches exceptions and wraps them with an IllegalStateException.

```
try {
    do my things...
} catch (final Exception e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Exception happened", e)
}
```

This all works fine except that while running integration tests, when the IllegalStateException is logged, it is not showing the caused by.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception happened
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:111)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData(ZooKeeper.java:1155)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetDataBuilderImpl$4.call(GetDataBuilderImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetDataBuilderImpl$4.call(GetDataBuilderImpl.java:293)
    at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:108)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetDataBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(GetDataBuilderImpl.java:290)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetDataBuilderImpl.forPath(GetDataBuilderImpl.java:281)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetDataBuilderImpl.forPath(GetDataBuilderImpl.java:42)
    at <my package line of "throw new IllegalStateException">.getConfig(ZookeeperConfigProvider.java:55)
    at <my package>.getConfig(ZookeeperConfigProvider.java:49)
    at <my package>.test_get_config_missing_resource(ZookeeperConfigProviderIT.java:118)
```

We are using logback, java 8 and JUnit

Logback configuration (but this does not look a it is being outputted by logback)

```
<configuration>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <!-- encoders are assigned the type
       ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

Any reason why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is the code.

Check the grep code here for KeeperException create method[Grep Code KeeperException](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.zookeeper/zookeeper/3.3.1/org/apache/zookeeper/KeeperException.java#KeeperException.create%28org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.Code%29)

It is simply throwing exception but not adding any message. That is why you do not see anything useful.

Also, because it gets return simply without logging the original issue.